# PHP Remove last word from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I've mysql query in array in the below format,i've to remove the last and

```
Array ( [0] => date = '2012-02-22' and time ='08:49' and  [1] => date = '2012-02-22' and time ='08:49' and )
```

I get this array as out put after putting into this function array_values();

I tried rtim and trim.

Thanks in-advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = array_map("remove_last_and", $arr);
function remove_last_and($el) {
    return preg_replace('/\s*and\s*$/i', '', $el);
}
```

Example:

```
$arr = array("date = '2012-02-22' and time ='08:49' and",  
             "date = '2012-02-22' and time ='08:49' and ");
$arr = array_map("remove_last_and", $arr);
function remove_last_and($el) {
    return preg_replace('/\s*and\s*$/i', '', $el);
}
var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(37) "date = '2012-02-22' and time ='08:49'"
  [1]=>
  string(37) "date = '2012-02-22' and time ='08:49'"
}
```

ps: I did not write the inline or anonymous function as I do not know what version of PHP you are using. But, as example, you can write as of php 5.3

```
$arr = array_map(function($el) {
            return preg_replace('/\s*and\s*$/i', '', $el);
       }, $arr);
```

ps: I do not think that use of `trim` or `rtrim` is good as it could remove the part of the query if the query is slightly different and has 'and' letters close to the end of the string.

Comment: @user1051322  Yes, everything is correct - I run the script before posting here.

Comment: I understood that you wanted to show exactly what you want to remove.

Comment: He does not seem to want to remove the **and** in the first element, only the last. So you remove to much.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following,

```
array_push(yourarray, rtrim(array_pop(yourarray), ' and'));
```

It will pop the last element, trim away the " and" at the end and then re-add the modified element to the array.

For example,

```
$yourarray = array("date = '2012-02-22' and time ='08:49' and",  
             "date = '2012-02-22' and time ='08:49' and ");

var_dump($yourarray);
array_push($yourarray, rtrim(array_pop($yourarray), ' and'));
var_dump($yourarray);
```

outputs the following

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(41) "date = '2012-02-22' and time ='08:49' and"
  [1]=>
  string(42) "date = '2012-02-22' and time ='08:49' and "
}

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(41) "date = '2012-02-22' and time ='08:49' and"
  [1]=>
  string(37) "date = '2012-02-22' and time ='08:49'"
}
```

So, the last " and" in the last element has been removed.

Comment: He wants to remove `and` at the end of the string in each element of array.

Comment: I edited my response to do just that one minute before you posted your comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array ( 0 => "date = '2012-02-22' and time ='08:49' **and**",  1 => "date = '2012-02-22' and time ='08:49' **and**");

function func($v){
    return rtrim($v,' **and**');
}
$b = array_map('func',$a);
```

Comment: :Warning: rtrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: Strange, i'm using an array_map function on array $a and in function func i'm using the rtrim which receives as parameter each element of the array. Are you sure you tested the entire example?

Answer (score 0):

use [trim()](http://us.php.net/manual/fr/function.trim.php) with an optional parameter 'and'

```
foreach($myarray as $element)
{
  trim($element, 'and')
}
```

**EDIT** : to remove only last "and" in the last element

```
 trim($myarray[count($myarray) -1] , 'and')
```